# Installing Bundler

Tags: ruby, bundler

Gem install bundler give me this error.

ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

What's the solution?

Comment: @spickermann : what is the duplicate question?

Comment: @Onikoroshi : Duplicate questions are linked automatically above the OP's question. Please find the link right below the title.

Answer (score 0):

It also could be due to outdated ssl files. Please check [this](http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html) for more detail information about the issue.Everything is described here

If you’ve installed RVM, try this:

```
$ rvm -v 
# rvm 1.19.1 (stable)
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs status all
# Certificates details
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
# update certificates
```